# Unity says No Sprite Editor Window is registered

Tags: unity-game-engine

Currently I'm trying to open the sprite editor for an image, but when I click "Sprite Editor" , I see the following message in my debug window:

**No Sprite Editor Window is registered. Please download 2D sprite package from Package Manager.**

These are the things I have done for debugging purpose:

Then I check my package manager and saw the 2D sprite package already installed:(version 1.0.0)

[image: 2D Sprite in Package Manager]

and the dependencies under {project}/Pacakges/manifest.json file is included. File contents are shown:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "com.unity.2d.sprite": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.collab-proxy": "1.2.16",
    "com.unity.ext.nunit": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.ide.rider": "1.1.0",
    "com.unity.ide.vscode": "1.1.2",
    "com.unity.package-manager-ui": "2.2.0",
    "com.unity.test-framework": "1.0.13",
    "com.unity.textmeshpro": "2.0.1",
    "com.unity.timeline": "1.1.0",
    "com.unity.ugui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.ai": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.androidjni": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.animation": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.assetbundle": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.audio": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.cloth": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.director": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.imageconversion": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.imgui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.jsonserialize": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.particlesystem": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.physics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.physics2d": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.screencapture": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.terrain": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.terrainphysics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.tilemap": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.ui": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.uielements": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.umbra": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unityanalytics": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequest": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestassetbundle": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestaudio": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequesttexture": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.unitywebrequestwww": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.vehicles": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.video": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.vr": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.wind": "1.0.0",
    "com.unity.modules.xr": "1.0.0"
  }
}
```

I also checked if I have set the image texture type to Sprite (2D and UI) before I click on Sprite Editor. The image inspector is shown:

[image: Image Inspector]

I tried to turn on the Read/Write Enabled button Under Image Inspector but I can't see the changes.

I also tried to import package from disk. First I delete the 2D Sprite Package in my package manager. Select to view packages In Project and click "add" (the + on the top-left corner) and click on the popup message "Add package from disk".
Go to {Unity Install path}\Editor{Unity 
 Version}\Editor\Data\Resources\PackageManager\BuiltInPackages\com.unity.2d.sprite and open the file "package.json". The package is loaded into my project automatically.

**Update:**

I also open another project and tried to open Sprite Editor but it also fails, I wonder if it was the problem of Unity itself. Please, it has been a few days and I still stuck here.

**Unity Version 2019.2.11f1**

So yeah Unity still give me the same warning and I can't modify the image through Sprite Editor. I guess there is something wrong with 2D Sprite package but I can't tell what the problem is. Anyone can help me figure out why this occurs and how to solve the problem? Many Thanks.

Comment: Could you add some screenshots of the things you mentioned? Also which Unity version?

Comment: Screenshots and Unity Version are added.

Comment: Just a shot into the dark but did you try to enable the `Read/Write Enabled`? And *did you try to turn it off and on again*?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I tried on and off respectively but no it doesn;t work

Comment: I would love to know what would caused by turning on the `Read/Write Enabled`button, any reason for me to do this?

Comment: this makes the pixel data - as the name says - read/write able. I guess it consumes more memory so Unity usually has it off. I thought it might be required to be able to use the Sprite Editor which seems to be not true ^^ With off and on again I referred to Unity or even your entire OS ;)

Answer (score 2):

1. Open your Package Manager... **Window > Package Manager.**
2. Click on the All Packages dropdown menu.
3. Select "Unity Registry".
4. Select "2D Animation" at the top of the list and apply/install.

Answer (score 1):

For Unity Version **2022.2.0f1**

**Window** -> **Package Manager** -> *[Type and Search "Sprite" in Search Bar]* -> **2D Sprite** -> **Install**